# Why does Python sock.recv receives data from 2 different packets?

Tags: python

The behavior is random.
I made pcaps with wireshark and tcpdump. Both show the packets length correctly.

When I do sock.recv, I randomly receive data from 2 consecutive packets. The behaviour is rare. From aprx 100 packets, 1-2 recv contains data from 2 consecutive packets.

The packets are sent very fast. Some are received bellow 1ms. However this is not a good indicator because other packets received in similar time diff are read correctly.

The socket is AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, non blocking and it is implemented using selectors.

The socket is a client

Comment: TCP is a *stream protocol*.  There is absolutely no connection between the individual chunks of data that are sent, and the individual chunks of data that are received; the *only* guarantee is that bytes are received in the same order they were sent.  If you need some higher-level structure to your data, it's entirely your responsibility to implement it - terminator characters or preceding length values are typical choices here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jasonharper says, TCP is a protocol that provides you with a stream of bytes.  It doesn't provide you with packets.

If you have a protocol that runs over TCP, and that has a notion of individual packets, there is *no* guarantee that a single chunk of bytes delivered on a TCP socket will begin at the beginning of a higher-level packet or will end at the end of the same higher-level packet.  A packet may be broken up between two chunks, and a chunk may include bits of more than one packet.  The only guarantee you get from TCP is that the data you get is received in the order in which it's transmitted.

As noted in the comment, protocols that run atop TCP generally either use some form of terminator to mark the end of a packet or put a byte count at the beginning of a packet to indicate how many bytes are in the packet.